# How to make CRUD in ASP.NET MVC with writing less code?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database

I am working in ASP.NET MVC to make an application. I have 4 tables. 4 tables have hierarchical data. I want to create a system CRUD for it.

Can someone tell me if there is a good way in MVC for writing auto-generated code for doing it. Please remember I am on MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Entity Framework and typed controller & views?

Comment: Yeah, i've read it: 
http://blog.willbeattie.net/2011/05/using-entity-framework-4-with-mysql.html